# Why do I need double brackets in R to deal with NA when computing this mean?

Tags: r

So I read in the following csv data into a variable called x.  The second column on the right has the header "z_data"

```
220      NA
221      NA
222      NA
223      NA
224      NA
225      NA
226   1.080
```

**If I issue following command, I get an error message "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA":**

```
mean(data["z_data"],na.rm=TRUE)
```

**If instead I do, I get the correct mean value:**

```
mean(data[["z_data"]],na.rm=TRUE)
```

What is the "double" square bracket doing?  I don't have to use it for the **max** command, just the **mean** and **median** commands.

Comment: `mean` works on `vectors` so either `mean(data[, "z_data"],na.rm=TRUE)` or the `[[` will extract the column into vector.  The warning you will get based on `mean.default` i.e `if (!is.numeric(x) && !is.complex(x) && !is.logical(x)) { warning("argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA")
        return(NA_real_)`

Comment: Try `class(data["z_data"])`